# instance var of CategoryController must be (Array(Array(Array(Int64 | String) | Array(String))) | Nil)

Tags: crystal-lang, amber-framework

unable to store data contain in abc.
it's showing an error

> instance variable `@ar` of `CategoryController` must be `(Array(Array(Array(Int64 | String) | Array(String))) | Nil)`, not `Array(Array(Int64 | String) | Array(String)))`

code sample:

```
 abc = [["", "Select"], [6_i64, "some"]]

 puts abc.class # => Array(Array(Int64 | String) | Array(String))

 @ar = [] of Array(Array(Int64 | String) | Array(String))

 @ar = abc # showing error
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error message is already in line for where you assign `@ar` the first time because the literal value has the same type as `abc`. However, the error message clearly states that the (expected) type of the instance variable and the actual type you try to assign, don't match. The assigned value is the item type of the array and can be *added*  to the array `@ar`, but not assigned to a variable holding such an array type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working [here](https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/6txj), going to need more context to find out the error. And also, comments should be done with `# Comment here`.

A guess would be that `@ar` in `CategoryController` is defined incorrectly.

Comment: Exactly I tried the same using different  pattern but it won't work with instance array variable.

Comment: To try and solve this, show the `CategoryController` class code

Comment: `code
CategoryController < ApplicationController
 getter category = Category.new 

def new abc = [["", "Select"], [6_i64, "parent"]] 
puts "-------------------------------->"
 puts abc
 puts abc.class @ar = [] of Array(Array(Int64 | String) | Array(String)) 
@ar = abc
 render "new.slang" 
  end
end
`